# How to replace a html comments using shell script

Tags: html, linux, shell, unix

I am trying to uncomment a line in html file using shell script but I am not able to write a sed command for this .

I have a line

```
<!--<url="/">-->
```

I need to uncomment this line using shell script

```
<url="/"/>
sed -i -e "s|'<!--<url="/"/>-->'|<url="/">|g" myFile.html
```

Any idea how to replace this comment?

Comment: Use a different separator for sed for example I often use % instead of ". That way you have no problems escaping quotes

Answer (score 3):

Use : 
`sed -re 's/(<!--)|(-->)//g'`

e.g: 
`echo '<HTML><!--<url="/">--> <BODY>Test</BODY></HTML>' | sed -re 's/(<!--)|(-->)//g'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape(add backslash) before `/` character.
Secondly, both crucial arguments should be separated with `/`, but not with `|`.
Use the following line:

```
sed -i 's/<!--<url="\/">-->/<url="\/">/g' myFile.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
sed -i 's|<!--<url="/">-->|<url="/">|g' myFile.html
```

It's better to use single quotes because it prevents interpretation of everything including double quotes.